# parity initializing snapshot whole night

Tags: parity, warp-sync

I have parity installed and synced. I went out of disk space. I moved the chain to bigger ssd. Then I started the parity service and let it run whole night. It did not finish.

in log I can see repeating lines like

```
IO Worker #3 INFO import  Snapshot initializing (378 chunks restored)  #7280022   19/25 peers      1 MiB chain   10 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
```

After about 2000 chunks I stopped it. How many chunks are there going to be ? This method should be fast, so I expect It should not take whole night

**Edit 1**

so `import  Snapshot initializing messages` changed eventually to `import  Syncing snapshot` and after few more hours stopped at `Syncing snapshot 3070/3070  #7280022   20/25 peers      2 KiB chain   10 MiB db  0 bytes queue   15 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs`

now there's reating message `IO Worker #3 INFO snapshot  Block restoration at #6870000` decreasing `at` by 100000 ever 2 minutes. I hope it's not going to zero. It would take another day.

Is this warp taking me to another galaxy ?

**Edit 2**

so after another restart it started syncing rest of the blocks